# Get specific array in a multidimensional array in Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty

I have the following multidim array;

```
[features] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => Foo
                [id_feature] => 9
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [value] => Bar
                [id_feature] => 10
            )

    )
```

Being very new to Smarty and its often butt-backwards approach to things, I have no clue where to begin, if I wanted to get a specific array based on the value of `id_feature` of that array.

That is to say, I'd need to put into a variable the array that for instance contains "9" for `id_feature`.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Just a suggestion: why not make `id_feature` the key for the parent array?

Comment: Love to, but I can't change the content of the array, as it's generated by Prestashop - and I'm looking to just make a theme more than change the behavior of the core. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this smarty code:

```
{foreach from=$features item=f}

  {if $f.id_feature eq 9}

   {$f.value}

   {$f.id_feature}

  {/if}

{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using in_array?

```
<?php
function getArray($search) {
   foreach($features as $val) {
      if(in_array($search, $val)){
        return $val;
      }
   }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you assigned something like this in PHP:

```
$features = array( 
    array("value" => "Foo", "id_feature" => 9), 
    array("value" => "Bar", "id_feature" => 10) );
$smarty->assign('features', $features);
```

In Smarty template, `{$features[0].value}` will give you `Foo`.

You can also traverse the array using `{for}` or `{foreach}` - check documentation http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/

Or even use `{php}` tag to write PHP directly:

```
{php}
  global $features;
  print_r($features);
{/php}
```